# Импорт файлов Flask

Tags: python, flask

Всем добрый, вечер. Есть небольшой проект на Flask, есть необходимость перенести адресацию в отдельный файл. Вроде как, все импорты подключены при этом ошибка::werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'login' instead?
В чем может быть проблема?

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask import current_app, g, render_template, redirect, request, session, url_for, flash
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
import fdb
import flaskr.db



app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
import flaskr.autorization
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY = 'username',
    DATABASE = os.path.join(app.instance_path, '/var/rdb/bdflask'),
    USER = 'sysdba',
    PASSWORD = 'masterkey',
    LIBRARY = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'rdb/libfbclient.so.3.0.6')
)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')
    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        g.user = user_id

@app.route('/login', methods =["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        conn = flaskr.db.get_db()
        error = None
        if conn is None:
            error = 'Подключение к базе данных не найдено'
        users = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM USERS').fetchall()
        print(users)
        if users is None:
            error = 'Записи в бд не найдены'
        else:
            for x in users:
                if x[2] == user and x[1] == password:
                    print('Вход выполнен')
                    clients = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM CLIENTS').fetchall()
                    for i in clients:
                        if i[1] == x[0]:
                            #вход клиента
                            session.clear()
                            session['user_id'] = x[0]
                            print('Клиент', session)
                            return redirect(url_for('home'))
                    masters = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM MASTER').fetchall()
                    for i in masters:
                        if i[1] == x[0]:
                            session.clear()
                            session['user_id'] = x[0]
                            print('Мастер',session)
                elif x[2] == user and x[1] != password:
                    error = 'Не верный пароль'
                    break
                elif x[2] != user:
                    error = 'Пользователь не найден'
        conn = flaskr.db.close_db()
        flash(error)
    return render_template('login.html')



@app.route('/register', methods =["POST", "GET"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        client_reg = { 'name': request.form['name'], 'login': request.form['login'],
                      'password': request.form['password']}
        error = None
        for key in client_reg:
            if client_reg[key]=='':
                error = "Поле " + key + " не заполнено"
                flash(error)

        if error is None:
            conn = flaskr.db.get_db()
            if conn is None:
                error = 'Подключение к базе данных не найдено'
                flash(error)
            else:
                copies = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT ID_USERS, LOGIN FROM USERS WHERE LOGIN = ?',
                                               (client_reg['login'],)).fetchall()
                for i in copies:
                    if i[1]==client_reg['login']:
                        error = f'Телефон  уже зарегистрирован'
                        flash(error)
                if error is None:
                    conn.cursor().execute(
                        "INSERT INTO USERS (LOGIN, PASSWORD) VALUES (?, ?)",
                        (client_reg['login'], client_reg['password'])
                    )
                    data = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LOGIN = ?',
                                                 (client_reg['login'],)).fetchall()
                    print(data[0][0])
                    conn.cursor().execute(
                        "INSERT INTO CLIENTS (ID_USERS,NAME) VALUES (?, ?)",
                        (data[0][0], client_reg['name'])
                    )
                    conn.commit()
                    return redirect(url_for("login"))

        #шифрование пароля
        conn = flaskr.db.close_db()
    return render_template('reg.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Импортируемый файл:

```
from flaskr import app
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask import current_app, g, render_template, redirect, request, session, url_for, flash
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
import fdb
import flaskr.db


@app.route('/home', methods =["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    if g.user is  None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        conn = flaskr.db.get_db()
        buttons = '0'
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'edit' in request.form:
                buttons = '1'
            if 'save' in request.form:
                buttons = '0'
                name = request.form['name']
                surname = request.form['surname']
                patronomic = request.form['patronomic']
                number_phone = request.form['phone']
                marka = request.form['mark']
                model = request.form['model']
                number_auto = request.form['number_auto']
                conn.cursor().execute('UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME = ?, SURNAME = ?, PATRONOMIC = ?,'
                                      'NUMBER_PHONE = ?, MARK_AUTO = ?, MODEL_AUTO = ?,'
                                      'NUMBER_AUTO = ? WHERE ID_USERS = ?', (name, surname, patronomic,
                                                                             number_phone, marka, model,
                                                                             number_auto, g.user,))
                conn.commit()
        data_clients_profile = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID_USERS= ?',
                                                     (g.user,)).fetchall()
        conn = flaskr.db.close_db()
        return render_template('home_client.html', data=data_clients_profile, buttons = buttons)
```

Comment: пробуй не ипортировать, а инклудить ```import runpath; globals().update(run_path(FILE.PY,globals()))```

Comment: @ganz это куда вставлять?

Comment: в основной файл, по сути выполняет код как-будто оно написан в том же файле